# conflict in network interface configuration of CentOS 6.5

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-esxi, linux-networking, vmware-esx

I am trying to create 2 network interfaces, one with DHCP and the other with static IP on a CentOS VM running on ESXi Server.

Content of file `ifcfg-eth0` is as follows:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=none
IPADDR=10.182.106.17
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=10.182.106.1
```

Content of file `ifcfg-eth1` is as follows:

```
DEVICE=eth1
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

Both interfaces get the same IP as 10.182.106.17. DHCP network is 10.136.*.* , so eth1 should be getting IP from that range.

When I manually take eth1 down and make it up again, it gets the IP from DHCP properly. Why doesn't it get the same thing while booting up? What am I doing wrong?

Every time before I reboot, I do remove /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have both the network service and NetworkManager running? If so, stop and disable NetworkManager or uninstall it altogether.

Comment: Yes. that was the issue. Thanks. Things are working fine now.
Will you please put this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have both the network service and NetworkManager running?

```
service NetworkManager status
```

If so, stop and disable NetworkManager:

```
service NetworkManager stop
chkconfig NetworkManager off
```

or uninstall it altogether:

```
yum remove NetworkManager
```